# How to avoid exception using CopyToDataTable() when no rows are found in a datatable

Tags: c#

> It throws an exception when no rows matches with the StudentID.

```
var InformationTable= StudentData.Tables[0].Select($"STUDENT_ID={StudetID}").CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: you need to check if any result found then call the method, if using C# 6 or above use `?` to handle : `var InformationTable= StudentData.Tables[0].Select($"STUDENT_ID={StudetID}")?.CopyToDataTable();`

Comment: Check the `Count` of `Select` before copy

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Thanks